# Understanding TypeError from decorator with function wrapper

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, decorator, typeerror

New to Python decorators and trying to understand the "flow" of the following code:

```
def get_text(name):
    return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)

def p_decorate(func):
    print "here's what's passed to p_decorate(func): %s" % func 
    def func_wrapper(name):
        print "here's what's passed to the inner func_wrapper(name) function: %s" % name
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))
    return func_wrapper

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text("fruit"))
print my_get_text("GOODBYE")

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
print my_get_text("veggies")
```

Why is it that the `print my_get_text("GOODBYE")` line gets a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`?

If I've already passed the `get_text(name)` function to `p_decorate(func)` in the line, even though I also gave `get_text()` a string "fruit", why can't I reassign what's passed for the `name` argument with `"GOODBYE"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to define `my_get_text` like this

```
my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)
```

because `p_decorate` needs a function as an argument and `get_text("fruit")` is a string, since that is what `get_text` returns when called. Hence the Error.

That's what a decorator is about, modifying a function. If you pass an argument to a function it is evaluated and the result (usually) doesn't have any connection with the function that generated it.